# How can I hide the part of the legend using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a plot using the code below and would like to hide the "mag" (size) legend but still keep the "depth" (color) legend.

`ggplot(quakes, aes(long, lat, size=mag, colour=depth)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try:

```
... + scale_size(guide="none") # As of Mar 2012

... + scale_size(legend = FALSE) # Deprecated
```

Comment: This still works, but I get a message saying "legend" argument is deprecated and to use guide="none". So ... + scale_size(guide="none") is the new syntax.

Comment: I keep trying to update these old answer, but it's tough to keep up!